# Building a 12 V DC 3-Wire Common Ground Power Supply - Model Rail Accessory Power

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking for a bit of confirmation for a project I'm doing for my model railway.

I'm going to be using a piece of equipment from an maker which requires a +12 V, 0 V, -12 Vdc supply. In the literature they suggest using 2 x wall-mounted plug-type transformers and tying together the +ve and -ve from the output to create a 3-wire output of +12 V, 0 V (common ground) and -12 V.

[image: instructions]

Now I'm trying to keep things neat and I'm thinking about getting two DIN-mounted 12 V Supplies from RS:

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/din-rail-power-supplies/1368305/

It doesn't need to be a precise 12 V as the PCB will run with some voltage variation. Can anyone see a reason why I can't use the DIN-mounted ones from RS (or similar, as there are loads on the internet)? I can make it enclosed then and a neater job etc.

Comment: If you click through to the [data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/6fac/0900766b8169352b.pdf) for that unit, one of the diagrams is labeled "Series Operation B". That's exactly what you're asking about, so I'd say it's okay to do it that way. The only drawback I see is that those units aren't currently available; that's why they only offer a back-order.

Comment: This seems like a generally unwise approach to a problem which really should be solved by using a unitary dual output mains supply or switching to a more modern device not requiring a dual supply (eg, not using op-amps, or using an H-bridge to drive the track).  Ultimately this site does not allow questions of *opinion* which is what yours really is: can you get this to work?  probably?  Should you?  **NO!**.  Consider for example what happens if you have one supply and not the other...

Comment: Yes the manual answers your question.